# Bulking shake review / suggested modifications? (17 yo)

Tags: diet, nutrition, protein-shakes, daily-caloric-intake, bulking

I am bulking and have crafted a shake that I drink 2x a day. Does this shake provide accurate nutritional value for bulking? What should I add/remove?

The shake:

```
1 banana (105 cal)
3 packets of original quaker's oatmeal (100 cal each)
1 tbsp peanut butter (100 cal)
1 scoop Gladiator protein powder (25g protein)(110 cal)
1 cup milk (100 cal)
Ice
```

#### Total Calories: 715 cal

#### Total Protein: 25g

Comment: Can you add some details on what the rest of your diet looks like? For instance, if you still live with your parents, can we assume that you have a decently varied diet otherwise? Meat, fish, vegetables, rice, potatoes etc?

Comment: I eat 6 meals a day. The other four are varied between 1 lb of grilled chicken, spaghetti with peas, 2 potatoes, quinoa, or a grilled chicken sandwich

Comment: Go on chronometer.com it is the most precise nutrition app so far, it tells you each type of protein, mineral,carb,fat and vitamins contained in a food. Wikipedia is quite precise too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bulking is a process by which a sustained calorie surplus (along with sufficient protein) is used in conjunction with resistance training to maximize an individual's potential rate of muscle growth. To maximize muscle protein synthesis, you want to be consuming something like 20-40 grams of protein 3-6 times per day with 3-5 hours between each meal (while also training). The muscle building benefit of a protein shake is that it is a fast to digest source of protein, and the most appropriate time to use such a shake is after a workout.

With that said, let's review your shake.

Pros

- You have about 44 grams of protein which is more than plenty.
- You have a lot of carbs to restore muscle glycogen.

Cons

- You're having it twice a day for some reason.
- You've got too much fat in it which slows digestion.
- You've got too many calories.

Unless you're just struggling to eat enough calories there is no need for you to have this many calories in the shake (much less to have it twice a day). I would suggest dropping your shake down to just skim milk & protein powder (as well as any specific flavorings/texture modifiers you would like to toss in). If you need the extra carbs for sports, that's fine, but if you're only doing resistance training it doesn't make sense to have that much.

Comment: I feel like I’m struggling to maintain a calorie surplus. Most of my other meals are small and contain little carbohydrates. I’m 150 lbs, so I need 3000 calories a day, right?

Comment: You might need 3000, or you might need 2500 or 3500. Energy needs vary based on more factors than just weight. The overall trends that the scale produces will show what sort of energy balance you are in (positive, neutral, negative). If you are gaining weight over time, you are in a surplus. If you gain a pound in a day, that's just water - which is why you need to monitor weight over time (3-4 weeks). I would suggest planning out your meals in advance - make a list of 10 or more that you would enjoy, and include calorie dense foods in those meals. That will help you to reach calorie targets.

Comment: If you're doing 6 meals a day and aiming for 3000 calories and you have a 250 calorie shake for example, they you just need 550 calories in each of your other meals. That's hardly a big target to aim for.

Comment: Ok! And if I have a bigger calorie surplus, will I gain more muscle?

Comment: That depends on other factors. You have to actually work out to gain muscle, and you haven't added any details about that. By default, a caloric surplus gains you fat, not muscle.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/powerbuilding/comments/bautle/6_day_powerbuilding_program_20/ this is my training regiment

Comment: @iamPres - This link includes a chart, a brief overview, and a study related to that question. In short, a notably bigger surplus should provide slightly more muscle gain at the cost of a lot more fat gain. https://www.instagram.com/p/B-zv7ARna9F/